# Why is the symbol of member function weak?

Tags: c++, gcc, symbols

I compiled this C++ code with `g++` (7.3.0).

```
struct C {
  __attribute__((noinline)) int foo() { return 0; };
};

int bar(C &c) { return c.foo(); }
```

And using `nm` I found that `foo` is weak. Is that due to the C++ specification or a decision of GCC?

The experiment flow:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -c -Og  
$ nm test.o  
0000000000000000 T _Z3barR1C  
0000000000000000 W _ZN1C3fooEv
```

Comment: Could please post the command line you used to compile the file and post the output of `nm`? `o found that bar is weak` `foo` is weak, not `bar`

Comment: @ KamilCuk, Sorry I mixed them up.

Comment: afaik weak is not something that the standard specifies; it's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is that C++ specification or decision of GCC?

A bit of both. Not that the C++ specification deals with strong or weak symbols (it doesn't). But it does affect GCC's behavior, since usually extensions try to build upon standard mandated behavior.

When you define a member function in the class body, it's automatically an inline function. In the C++ language, an inline function is a function that can have multiple definitions, so long as they appear in different translation units. It's not a problem, because in C++, an inline function must have the exact same definition in every translation unit (down to the token sequence). So even though they are "different" definitions, they are identical, and so can be reduced to a single one at some point.

The function doesn't have to actually be inlined at the call site. As far as C++ is concerend, `inline` is about the one-definition rule and linkage. So you have that, there can be multiple definitions of `C::foo` according to the spec.

And then you specify `__attribute__((noinline))`, so the function cannot be physically inlined, and so every TU must contain a symbol for the function.

This leaves only one choice. The symbol must be weak, otherwise the different symbols in different translation units will interfere with eachother. By making the symbol weak, you can have your mandatory definition and avoid physically inlining the function, while the C++ specification is upheld. Those different symbols stand for the exact same function, and so any one of them can "win" when linking.